# Looping through webpages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to loop through different pages of a site with the following code:

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from random import randint

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}

pages = range(1,6)

for page in pages:

    page = requests.get("https://www.myhome.ie/rentals/ireland/property-to-rent?page=" + str(page), headers=headers) 

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    rent_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='PropertyListingCard__Content MhHelper__Flex--spaced')

    sleep(randint(5,10))

rent = []

for container in rent_div:
    name = container.find('div', class_='PropertyListingCard__Price').text
    rent.append(name)

print(len(rent))
```

I've got 5 pages with 20 results on each so the output should be 100. The problem is I am only ever getting 20 from the last page of whatever range I input.

I read that this may be because that the data is replacing itself in each loop which may be the case. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the following changes:

1. Move the declaration of `rect = []` above the `for page in pages:` loop.
2. Move the `for container in rent_div:` loop to be within the `for page in pages:` loop.

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from random import randint

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}

pages = range(1,6)

rent = []

for page in pages:

    page = requests.get("https://www.myhome.ie/rentals/ireland/property-to-rent?page=" + str(page), headers=headers) 

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    rent_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='PropertyListingCard__Content MhHelper__Flex--spaced')

    sleep(randint(5,10))

    for container in rent_div:
        name = container.find('div', class_='PropertyListingCard__Price').text
        rent.append(name)

print(len(rent))
```

**Update**

I assume that you have the call to `sleep` in the code because you are concerned with overwhelming the server and causing an error. Still, you seem to be sleeping an excessively long amount of time, which can be reduced. Also, since your are making requests to the same website repeatedly, you should probably use a `Session` instance (I have also removed some extraneous `import` statements):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
rent = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    for page in range(1,6):
        page = session.get("https://www.myhome.ie/rentals/ireland/property-to-rent?page=" + str(page), headers=headers) 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
        rent_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='PropertyListingCard__Content MhHelper__Flex--spaced')
        sleep(randint(1, 2)) # reduce the time
        for container in rent_div:
            name = container.find('div', class_='PropertyListingCard__Price').text
            rent.append(name)

print(len(rent))
print(rent)
```

Comment: ahhh ok...somehow I missed out on that indent in the guide I'm following and not sure how I put rent = [] in the wrong place. Thanks for the response and for the follow up cleaning! It is working now